# my date and amount is not getting updated on api is being updated as empty string

Tags: reactjs

In my code, `date` and `amount` is not being updated. I have entered the value in post method but its getting updated as an empty string. Can anyone suggest me a solution?
Here is my code of checkout form:

```
  const Checkout = () => {
      const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
      const [date, setDate] = useState("");
      const[amount,setAmount]=useState("")
      let today = new Date()
    let Currdate = today. getDate() + '-' + parseInt(today. getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today. getFullYear()
    
      const postData = (e) => {
        axios
          .post("http://localhost:3003/order", {
            name,location,date,amount
          })
          .then((res) => {
           
            setUsers([
              ...users,
              {
                id: res.data.id,
                name: res.data.name,
                location: res.data.location,
                date: Currdate,
                amount: total,
              },
            ]);
          },);
      };
        const state = useSelector((state) => state.addItem)
    
        var total = 0;
        const itemList = (item) => {
            
            total = total + item.price;
            return (
               .....
            );
        }
    
  return (
     <>
  {state.map(itemList)}
  <strong>Rs.{total}</strong>
  <form className="card p-2">
 <input onChange={(e) =>setName(e.target.value)}  value={name}/>
  <input onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}  value={location}   />                           </>
export default Checkout
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `date` and `amount` is not being updated because you are only inserting a new object in `users` array. To update them write `setDate(Currdate);` and `setAmount(total);` after `setUsers([...users,{id: res.data.id,name: res.data.name,location: res.data.location,date: Currdate,amount: total,},]);`;

Comment: its not working

Comment: I guess this should work, If it's not working then I will need to see full code. @AnanthapadmanabhanG